# eas build for ios error: The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo, eas

I am using eas build for my expo-based react native app. I am unable to build for ios and keep getting the error during Install pods with the following error log:

106 [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:
107 The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.
108 Error: Unknown error. See logs for more information.

I have searched many stackoverflow related questions which I have used in editing the Podfile at node_modules/react-native/template/ios/Podfile. An excerpt of the Podfile is shown below:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'


platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

# added only these 5 lines to the Podfile
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
use_modular_headers!


target 'HelloWorld' do
  config = use_native_modules!


  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()
  
  ...
```

Questions:

1. Are the added 5 lines in the appropriate place in the code? I have tried adding them just below the
2. Do I have to edit code elsewhere apart from the Podfile? If yes, where and what code.

Been battling this for up to 2 weeks now. Any help would be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Searched and searched, and mixed and matched, and then trial and error. The following has worked for me.

In node_modules/react-native/template/ios/Podfile, i changed the Podfile to this

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'HelloWorld' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    # :hermes_enabled => true,
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'HelloWorldTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Then also added **plugins** to my app.config.js (similarly if you are using app.json).

```
module.exports = {
  expo: {
    name: "appName",
    slug: "appName",
    scheme: "appName",
    version: "1.0.0",
    orientation: "portrait",
    icon: "./assets/icon_1.png",
    userInterfaceStyle: "light",
    splash: {
      image: "./assets/entry_page.png",
      resizeMode: "contain",
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    },
    updates: {
      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 0
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: [
      "**/*"
    ],
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: "com.myaooo.appName"
    },
    android: {
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: "./assets/icon_1.png",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
      },
      package: "com.myaooo.appName",
      versionCode: 5,
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: process.env.PLACES_API_KEY
        }
      }
    },
    web: {
      favicon: "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    extra: {
      eas: {
        placesApiKey: process.env.PLACES_API_KEY,
        youtTubeApiKey: process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY,
        webApiKey: process.env.WEB_API_KEY,
        firebaseApiKey: process.env.apiKey,
        expoGoogleClientId: process.env.EXPO_GO_GOOGLE_CONSOLE_client_id,
        expoAndroidId: process.env.EXPO_GO_GOOGLE_CONSOLE_androidClientId,
        expoIosId: process.env.EXPO_GO_GOOGLE_CONSOLE_iosClientId,
        clientID: process.env.WEB_clientId,
        expoGoogleClientSecret: process.env.EXPO_GO_GOOGLE_CONSOLE_client_secret
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
        android: { 
          compileSdkVersion:31,
          targetSdkVersion:31,
          buildToolsVersion:"31.0.0"
          },
        ios: {
          deploymentTarget:"13.0",
          useFrameworks: "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

In essence you have to make modifications on the podfile (add the modular headers) and also on the app.json / app.config.js (add the plugins) files.

Comment: thanks so much for figuring this out. helped me immensely!

Answer (score 2):

```
[
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "ios" :{
        "deploymentTarget" : "13.4",
        "useFrameworks" : "static"
      }
    }
  ]
```

I added this to my app.json. I got the deploymentTarget value from my podfile in ios/podfile
From here-->

```
platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'
```

And then I ran `eas build --platform ios` and the build the just passed.

Comment: Thank you SO much, that fixed it for me on Expo v50. It stopped working for me on my last build for some reason after almost a year of working. This should be the accepted answer.